# If error, assign a specific value to variable

Tags: haskell

so I have this code fragment: `where exponent = read (tail (dropWhile (/= '^') (head xs))) :: Int` but there is a possibility of the list inside `tail` being empty, so that would mean there would be an error looking for a tail inside an empty list. Is there a way to do something like: `if error: exponent = 1` ?

Here is the full function if it helps in any way :)

```
internalRepresentation :: [String] -> [(Int,Char ,Int)]
internalRepresentation xs
    |null xs = []
    |all isDigit (head xs) = (read (head xs), ' ', 0) : internalRepresentation (tail xs)
    |head (head xs) == '-' = (-read (takeWhile isDigit (pos_mon)) :: Int, head (dropWhile isDigit (pos_mon)), exponent) : internalRepresentation (drop 1 xs)
    |otherwise = (read (takeWhile isDigit (head xs)) :: Int, head (dropWhile isDigit (head xs)), exponent) : internalRepresentation (drop 1 xs)
    where pos_mon = tail (head xs)
          exponent = read (tail (dropWhile (/= '^') (head xs))) :: Int
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

The functions `read`, `head`, and `tail` are partial which means that they can fail with an error as you have experienced. That is why many people avoid those functions. Personally, I would write it like this:

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

internalRepresentation' :: String -> (Int, Char, Int)
internalRepresentation' xs =
  case reads xs of
    [(n, "")] -> (n, ' ', 0)
    [(n, x:xs')] ->
      case readMaybe (drop 1 (dropWhile (/= '^') (x:xs'))) of
        Just e -> (n, x, e)
        Nothing -> error "Malformed exponent"
    _ -> error "Malformed internal representation"

internalRepresentation :: [String] -> [(Int, Char, Int)]
internalRepresentation xs = map internalRepresentation' xs
```

You can probably avoid that ugly `drop 1 (dropWhile (/= '^') (x:xs'))` too if you constrain your input a bit more. But I'm not completely sure what this function is actually supposed to do, so I can't help much more.

For example, if you only want to parse strings that look exactly like `123^456` (without other characters in between), then you can write it like this:

```
internalRepresentation' xs =
  case reads xs of
    [(n, "")] -> (n, ' ', 0)
    [(n, '^':xs')] ->
      case readMaybe xs' of
        Just e -> (n, '^', e)
        Nothing -> error "Malformed exponent"
    _ -> error "Malformed internal representation"
```